# Strip Z dimension on GeoDjango (Force 2D geometry)

Tags: django, gis, postgis, geodjango, geos

In my project I need to import some geometry from **shapefiles**.

Some of these are `MULTIPOLYGON Z` type, but all Z coordinates are 0-value.

When I try to save the geometry, I get the error:

> "Geometry has Z dimension but column does not"

What is the best way to strip the Z dimension?

My code:

```
ds = DataSource(file_path, encoding='ISO-8859-1')
layers = ds[0]

#need something HERE to coerce geometry to 2D

obj=MyModel(geometry=GEOSGeometry(layers[0].geom.hex))
obj.save()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for replying, Mike T.

The thing is that I need to make it using the [GeoDjango framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/contrib/gis/), without directly accessing **Postgis database**.

Actually, after hard work, I found a solution. I need to use `.clone()` method from [`OGRGeometry`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/contrib/gis/gdal/#django.contrib.gis.gdal.OGRGeometry) object.  Now, I could change `coord_dim` property. If I change `coord_dim` in the original object, nothing happens.

Here is my code:

```
ds = DataSource(file_path, encoding='ISO-8859-1')
layers = ds[0]

#HERE IS THE TRICK
new_layer = layers[0].geom.clone() 
new_layer.coord_dim = 2

obj=MyModel(geometry=GEOSGeometry(layers[0].geom.hex))
obj.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL access, you can get this with [`ST_Force2D` (or `ST_Force_2D` for older versions)](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Force_2D.html).

You can also correct the source table by modifying the type, e.g.:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
  ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(MultiPolygon,4326) USING ST_Force2D(geom);
```